# Unknown Notation - Brace connect two notes

Tags: notation, sheet-music

[image: The Notation]

I dont know what exactly reffering to. Anyone can explaining to me?

EDIT: this notation appear on "[450 Noëls](https://cn.imslp.org/wiki/450_No%C3%ABls_(Rouher,_Edouard_Marcel_Victor))" by Rouher, Edouard Marcel Victor

Comment: Can you say which of the 450 pieces? Which edition of the IMSLP options?

Comment: @AndyBonner is the IMSLP #314558 and #314560

Comment: And I see now, it's throughout. Noel #2 uses it within the piece. I hope an organist can chime in, but it seems to me to have to do with indicating registers/stops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The piece is for (pipe) organ. Organs generally have more than one keyboard - one or more for the hands (manuals) and one for the feet. See for example [this page at organtutor.byu.edu](https://organtutor.byu.edu/content/large-organ-console). These different keyboards are linked to various **stops**. Different stops control different sounds. The selection of stops (and assignment of particular notes to particular keyboards) is often left to the performer, and is known as **registration**.

In the scores you are looking at, someone - either composer or editor - has specified particular assignments of notes to keyboards. You can see in the pages before the scores this sort of thing:

[image: Legend of what symbols indicate what keyboards]

Note the G, P, R on the left.

Then, in a score, for example #221:

[image: Start of a score, with notes braced across the grand staff, and "R" highlighted]

The R indicates that *all the braced voices* are to be played on the keyboard that R refers to (Swell, in English)

Sometimes the indicated keyboard changes midpiece:

[image: Section of score where indicated keyboard changes]

Here, the instruction is to use Swell for the top two voices of the *piano* section, but (optionally) switch to Great-Organ or Choir for the *forte* section.